# Git with Blink1 feedback

Tags: bash, git

I just bought a Blink1 lately and I'm trying to integrate it with Git.

```
alias git='function __git() {
    OUTPUT="$(blink1-tool --list)"
    EXPECTED="no blink(1) devices found"

    git "$@"

    if ! [ "$OUTPUT" = "$EXPECTED" ]
    then
        if [ $? = 0 ]
        then
            blink1-tool --green --blink 1
        else
            blink1-tool --red
        fi
    fi
}; __git'
```

However, when I make a new in my iTerm, it blinks before any git commands. And if I execute a command like `git status`, it blinks 4 times, but I only see 1 log of the blink:

```
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
blink 1 times rgb:0,ff,0:
set dev:0:0 to rgb:0x00,0xff,0x00 over 300 msec
set dev:0:0 to rgb:0x00,0x00,0x00 over 300 msec
```